# Setting up an Adapter with Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to find the correct way to set up a Camel route, and need to decide which part to model as a Camel-Producer.

Following setting:

On the frontend (website) a user sets up some parameters, and triggers data-transformation.

These parameters are used to build up a Query for a rest-client (ClientA). The client receives all the data that needs to be transformed.

After transformation we have a second client (ClientB) for POSTing the transformed data to a second REST-service.

For this, I set up the following route:

```
from("direct:start").to(ClientA).process(DataTransformations).to(ClientB)
```

Using a ProducerTemplate to put in Parameters given by a user, which are needed for ClientA, which is a Camel-http4-component.

What gives me a headache are the two "to"s in the route, since i seldom see this in examples. Is this the correct way to set up the route, or am I misunderstanding the concept of a camel-producer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need use ProducerTemplate this time.
You camel route can just be

```
from("direct:start").to("http4://service1?xxx").process(DataTransformations).to("http4://service2");
```

You can set the message headers to change query parameters.

Comment: thanks. but how do I trigger the process without a ProducerTemplate?

Comment: The DataTransformations processor will be called after the response of service1 sent back to camel.